# Python regex to capture a description

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to capture any group of words with exactly one space in between them and could contain non alphabetic characters. 
For example with the string

```
HOSE 1/4 X BSP F 3/8             Each
```

I would like to fetch only `HOSE 1/4 X BSP F 3/8`.

I have tried the pattern `(?P<descr>(\w+\s)+)` with no success. Also sometimes the '/' is there and sometimes its not.

**NOTE**: I'm using the *invoice2data* library to fetch line items from an invoice and a regex is required.

Comment: Instead of posting "edit", please format your code properly. Everything you type into an editor or console, or that comes from a text file should be formatted as "code". That formatting preserves the spaces.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Im not too sure how to write it out so that the spaces remain. Stack overflow is removing the spaces

Comment: Don't forget to remove the edit...

Comment: Maybe `^\S+(?:\s\S+)*`? Or just `s.split('  ')[0]`. See https://ideone.com/AIqmLk

Comment: @MadPhysicist Got it, Thanks

Comment: I forgot that the consecutive spaces are always shrunk  in comments, in my above comment, there are two spaces, as per the demo link.

Comment: Looks like the named capturing groups are required in *invoice2data*, I added the named group to my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If regex was not required you could easily get what you need with `s.split('  ')[0]`.

If you need to use a regex you may use

```
^(?P<descr>\S+(?:\s\S+)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TSnPTf/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `(?:\s\S+)*` - 0 or more repetitions of a single whitespace followed with 1+ non-whitespace chars.

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/AIqmLk):

```
s = "HOSE 1/4 X BSP F 3/8             Each"
print ( s.split('  ')[0] )
# => HOSE 1/4 X BSP F 3/8

import re
m = re.search(r'^(?P<descr>\S+(?:\s\S+)*)', s)
if m:
  print( m.group("descr") )
# => HOSE 1/4 X BSP F 3/8
```

Comment: @MadPhysicist  I copied it from my comment, and spaces are shrunk by SO there. Certainly there are two spaces

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used the regex `^(?P<descr>\S+(?:\s\S+)*)` and it worked

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty clear that the description can contain arbitrary text, so `\w` does not apply. What separates the description from the rest of the line is an unusually large number of spaces. You don't really need regex in that case:

```
line = 'HOSE 1/4 X BSP F 3/8             Each\n'
descr = line.split('   ')[0]
```

I used three spaces here as a safe bet. If the number is fixed and you know it up front, use that instead.

Since it appears you require a regex solution using a named capturing group, one option is to use positive lookaheads:

```
(?P<descr>^.+?(?=   ))
```

`+?` will do a non-greedy capture on any characters at the beginning of a line, as long as they are followed by three or more spaces. The trailing spaces themselves are not captured because they are checked by a positive lookahead `(?=   )`.

Comment: I really need a regex for this case as I'm using the invoice2data library to fetch line items from an invoice and a regex is required

Comment: @West. Fair enough. What method will be applied to the regex? Findall? search? fullmatch? It matters a lot. Are you looking for something that will return a capture group? In fact, could you please add that information to the question? It seems important.

Comment: @West. I've updated with what I think is your simplest option

Comment: @West. Use `.` for spaces, `\n` for newline in comments

Comment: I cant format my comment properly with code but yes I tried this and it picks up strings that occur before

Answer (score 0):

You may use this regex with capture group in python:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'HOSE 1/4 X BSP F 3/8        Each'
>>> print (re.findall(r'(?:^\s?|\S\s)(\S+(?: \S+)*)', s))
['HOSE 1/4 X BSP F 3/8']
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tpj9aO/3/)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:^\s?|\S\s)`: Make sure we have start position or a space after start or a space after non-space character
- `(\S+(?: \S+)*)`: Match 1 or more substring separated by a single space

Comment: I'm trying to get the output as one, i.e. `HOSE 1/4 X BSP F 3/8`

Comment: Thanks I tried this but it cut off the word 'HOSE' so the result was `E 1/4 X BSP F 3/8`. Im sure knowing the actual capture method required would have been good but I'm not too sure what method it is though I assume could be Match

Comment: It is strange because I copy pasted code from my terminal as-is and generated output is also shown here.